# Passing variables to menu

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

Is there a way to pass a variable set on a page to a menu that is displayed on that page?

For example, if I have a template that sets a variable to true or false, for instance, and that page includes a header, which in turn displays a menu, is there any way for me to use that variable in the menu?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this should help.

The menu helper function takes three parameters.
1. The menu name
2. The menu template to use
3. An array of parameters that get passed to the template.

Ordinarily you will use `{{menu('main-nav')}}` but you can also use `{{menu('main-nav', '_sub_menu.twig', {'varname':'varval'})}}`

That will now make the `varname` variable available in the menu template.